# Change struct field in GDB using a gdb.value

Tags: python, struct, gdb, field

I am defining a convenience variable in gdb

```
>set $param = (T_packet*)malloc(sizeof(T_packet))
```

I can retrieve it via Python

```
>p = gdb_helper.parse_and_eval("$param")
<gdb.Value at 0x7f30b42f9170>
```

show the fields of the struct

```
>python print(p.dereference())

{ID_PACKET = 0 , L_PACKET = 0}
```

Try to change a field (C equivalent: p->ID_PACKET=1)

```
p.dereference()["ID_PACKET"] = 1
>"Setting of struct elements is not currently supported"
```

Is there way to update the value of the field ID_Packet inside p using GDB's Python API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to set a value using the `Value` API.  This is just a little hole in gdb (I looked but could not find a bug for this, so perhaps filing one would be a good thing to do).

Meanwhile you can work around it, with a bit of difficulty, using `gdb.parse_and_eval`.  The idea is to get the address of the field in question, then form an expression like `*(TYPE *) 0xADDR = VALUE`.  Alternatively you can write directly to memory using `Inferior.write_memory`.

Both of these approaches will fail in some situations, for example you cannot write to a register this way, preventing this from working on a structure that's been split apart due to SRA optimization.